# send() call only works for telnet in socket

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, tcp, telnet

I am using windows sockets with c++. In the following call I am trying to reply a message to the socket that just connected.

I tried connecting using a dummy client in c++. It would connect but the recv() would not receive anything.

Then I tried using telnet, it worked instantly, just as i wanted.

```
SOCKET s = accept(ls, (sockaddr*)&clientSin, &s_len);

            if (s == INVALID_SOCKET) {
                cerr << "Error in accept call: " << WSAGetLastError();
            }
            else {
                cout << "Connection accepted at , socket no. :" << s << endl;
                //adding to list of incoming sockets
                inactiveList.push_back(s);
                //send message to client requesting credentials
                char buff[10];
                
                // the character 'x' is a code to the client to provide the server with the credentials
                buff[0] = 'x';
                buff[1] = '\0';
                //send(s, buff, 2, 0);
                if (send(s, "From Vic: ", 10, 0) == INVALID_SOCKET)
                {
                    int errorcode = WSAGetLastError();
                    cerr << "send to client failed: " << errorcode << endl;
                    closesocket(s);
                    continue;
                }
                Sleep(1000);
                if (send(s, "From Vic: ", 10, 0) == INVALID_SOCKET)
                {
                    int errorcode = WSAGetLastError();
                    cerr << "send to client failed: " << errorcode << endl;
                    closesocket(s);
                    continue;
                }
                
            }
```

the recv code is:

```
tnb = 0;
    while ((nb = recv(s, &buff[tnb], LINESZ - tnb, 0)) > 0)
    {
        tnb += nb;
    }
    /* If there was an error on the read, report it. */
    if (nb < 0)
    {
        printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    if (tnb == 0)
    {
        printf("Disconnect on recv");
    }
    /* Make the response NULL terminated and display it.  Using C output */
    printf("tnb = %d\n", tnb);
    buff[tnb] = '\0';
    puts(buff);
```

Comment: Your `send` code is probably fine. Please show your `recv` code.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue. A failed `send` call doesn't return INVALID_SOCKET, it returns SOCKET_ERROR.  They are probably both the same.

Comment: You should explicitly check for `tnb >= LINESZ` in your recv loop for breaking out.  On windows, length is signed, but everywhere else the len parameter to recv is unsigned.

Comment: Did you at least add a printf statement in your while loop on the recv side?

Comment: Also, don't forget to null terminate `buff` before printing it.  Otherwise, you risk printing out more than what you actually received for that line.

Comment: My psychic powers suggset that LINESZ is way bigger than what you are actually sending. Hence, it just stays in the loop forever waiting for more data.

Comment: What is your proof that "recv() would not receive anything"? The shown code loops until `recv`() returns 0 or the buffer size is exceeded. Until that happens `recv()` gets repeatedly called. What is the proof you can show of this not happening, for some reason?

Comment: Also, not checking if `recv` explicitly returns 0. I amended my answer below to cover this case as well.

Answer (score 0):

Taking all my comments and turning it into an answer.

I suspect your recv loop is continuing forever because you haven't sent enough data to make it break out of the loop.

Change this:

```
while ((nb = recv(s, &buff[tnb], LINESZ - tnb, 0)) > 0)
{
    tnb += nb;
}
```

To this: (notice that I'm allocating +1 for the array buff)

```
char buff[LINESZ+1]; // +1 for null terminator
buff[0] = '\0';
tnb = 0;
while (tnb < LINESZ)
{
    nb = recv(s, &buff[tnb], LINESZ-tnb, 0);
    if (nb < 0)
    {
        printf("Error on socket: %d\n", (int)WSAGetLastError());
        break;
    }
    else if (nb == 0)
    {
        printf("Remote socket closed\n");
        break;
    }

    printf("Received: %d bytes\n", (int)nb);

    tnb += nb;
    buff[tnb] = '\0'; // null terminate the end of the buffer so it will print reliably
}
```

Comment: This works however, is there a way in which you can break out of the loop without the socket closing. My server sends the message, but the client is on a loop and just keeps listening even when there is no more message coming.

Comment: You need to build that into your own protocol. Add your own delimiters between messages.  For example, scan the buffer you receive and look for a `'\n'` char